# JSON to UITableView IOS Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I'm trying to get JSON to UITableView from a URL API.

Below is my code for my view controller.

I'm quite new to Objective-C.

Just wanting to know what I should use to make this happen. This is my code below and I keep getting errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Please remember I'm really new to this so I will need a detailed explanation and working through.

ViewController.h

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSError *error;
    NSString *url_string = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://django-env2.55jfup33kw.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/Musician/?format=json"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:url_string]];
    NSMutableArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    //NSLog(@"json: %@", json);

   // NSString *mystring = json[1];
   // NSLog(@"json: %@", mystring);


    NSMutableArray *myMutableArray = [json mutableCopy];

    NSArray *myArray = [myMutableArray copy];

    NSLog(@"json: %@", myArray);


    self.greekLetters = @[@"test", @"test2"];




}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return myArray.count;
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        //cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    NSDictionary *cellDict = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [cellDict objectForKey:@"address_line1"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [cellDict objectForKey:@"zipcode"];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: what is the issue with the code ?

Comment: Getting errors? What errors? What's prints `cellDict`? Note that you should `[myTableView reloadData];` once you got the JSON.

Comment: Please add all details if your json is nil or any of your data sources arrays are nil or are the delagte methods getting called!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON & Xcode 6 UITableView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26052161/json-xcode-6-uitableview)

Comment: Pavel don't give possible duplicate better to answer to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step-1**

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
  // create the array 
  NSMutableArray *myMutableArray;
 }
@end
```

**Step-2**

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSError *error;
    NSString *url_string = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://django-env2.55jfup33kw.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/Musician/?format=json"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:url_string]];
    NSMutableArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

       // allocate the memory of your array
       myMutableArray = [NSMutableArray array];

     // check your dictionary contains values or not
     if (json)
    {
     // add the data to your array
    [myMutableArray addObject:json];
    [yourTableViewname reLoaddata]; // refresh the table
    }

 }
```

your JSON output is

[image]

**step-3**

```
  - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return myMutableArray.count;
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        //cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    NSDictionary *cellDict = [myMutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [cellDict objectForKey:@"first_name"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [cellDict objectForKey:@"last_name"];

    return cell;
}
```